# Minify css in contao

Tags: contao

I need to speedup my site.When looking for solutions google suggests

- Compacting CSS code can save many bytes of data and speed up download
  and parse times.
- Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

  How to minify css in contao? Is there any configuration available?

Comment: Use https://cssminifier.com/ to minify css and replace with original or add new

Comment: I need to know whether the contao CMS has any configuration for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It does, you could even use scss and get minified css from that.
First go to the theme, layout and add an external css, less or scss file:
[image]

Then go to settings and activate the minification:
[image]

Comment: Activated the settings . But the css files are not minified.Is there any effect when adding the above css frameworks?

Comment: Where do I find these settings? I don't find them.

Comment: @MAESTRO_DE which Contao Version? I can not find them either in Contao 4, but I definitely can remember them from Contao 3! The screenshots look like C3 at least.

Comment: Today I would recommend to use a pre processor like webpack or gulp, work with scss and add the minified file to your layout.